# Is there any timeline to predict the support of HTML5 features? Any source?

Tags: html, timeline, prediction

Planning to use HTML5 in a big project, I need to make an exact timeline for future changes.

Is there any source to tell me when a particular feature of HTML5 will be ready? Is there a roadmap for HTML5 support for each particular web engine?

Just for some more details, I’m working on a social/video sharing site. I want to use new features from CSS3 to HTML5 to JavaScript. Don’t tell me “You can use `<video>` right now” because I know that!!

*Also consider the fact that it takes some time for all people to update their browsers to new ones*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to make an exact time-line for future changes.

So you want Microsoft, Apple, Mozilla, Opera and Google to tell you exactly when they’ll be done adding features to their browsers? Just e-mail them, I’m sure they’ll get right on that :)

Naw, interesting question. I don’t think any browser manufacturers commit to implementing specific features particularly far into the future. In the case of HTML5, the spec itself says that the spec won’t be done until there are two agreeing implementations, so it’s very much a matter of “wait until an implementation ships”.

In the case of WebKit and Firefox, they‘re open-source projects, which I imagine makes it more difficult to commit to far-future dates. Then again, I seem to remember Microsoft being a bit late with Vista, so it’s probably difficult to commit to dates for closed-source projects as well. If you could edit your question with the exact date when your social video sharing site will be finished, that’d be a good start.

A quick Google turns up:

#### Internet Explorer

Microsoft have got IE 9 in beta. This page claims to be some sort of roadmap: http://microsoft-journal.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!A33F7112F6C1D499!878.entry

There’s also their [Internet Explorer Blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/)

#### Firefox

Mozilla announced their plans for 3.6 here: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/Namoroka

Couldn’t find a similar document for 4 (which was originally announced as 3.7), but robertc pointed to this document which details the HTML5 (and CSS3) features added in Firefox 4: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Firefox_4_for_developers

#### WebKit (Safari and Chrome)

“Apple doesn’t comment on future products” — http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/FAQ

But the WebKit team do have a blog, [Surfin’ Safari](https://webkit.org/blog/)

#### Opera

Folks were apparently clamouring for a roadmap last year: http://dev.opera.com/forums/topic/294965

Comment: thank you for the links you provided in your response. wiki.mozilla.org was helpful and also dev.opera.com . I'm going to make a road map for my own project which depends on the answer to my question. I will launch first version about 4 months later. but it is always better to be ready for future changes during development.

Comment: Good spot for those. Microsoft have the Internet Explorer Blog too, and the Safari guys have Surfin’ Safari, although it’s fairly infrequently updated (I’ve added both to the answer). It’ll be interesting to see if you hit your timeline — Stack Overflow was originally estimated at 6–8 weeks, it ended up taking a bit longer :)

Comment: 3.6 didn't get renamed to 4, 3.7 did.  Doesn't look like there's a similar document for 3.7/4, I think this is the closest thing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Firefox_4_for_developers

Comment: @robertc — Oh! Of course, quite right. Answer corrected accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

Yes:

[When can I use...](http://caniuse.com/)

Comment: Thank you. It is a good source. but it just tells it will be ready in 2011 OR LATER!!!! I want an exact time-line. be sure, companies working on web engines and web browsers have plan for this. I want to know what is their plans, their time-lines.

Comment: This is an extremely interesting and very useful site, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on your target audience. If it is South Korean middle aged businessmen with 99% IE6 penetration, you're not likely to be able to use anything fancy any time soon. If it's art directors working in advertising, you can probably already use whatever bleeding edge feature Webkit has implemented.

Check your logs, and use the site sAc linked.